# Missing expression in split syntax in perl

Tags: perl

I haven't done much (any really) perl programming and today someone sent me some code to review in perl.  Mostly I can understand what's happening but there was one line that I simply cannot get my head around, the split function in the code block below

```
 while(<>) {
   chomp;
   my($v1, $v2, $v3, $v4) = split(/,/);

   # ....
```

I read this [blog post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perl-split-function/) and it suggests that the syntax is valid (and I believe that it is).  But what I don't understand is what exactly is being split with the `Expression` missing

Comment: Following web page explains it all https://perlmaven.com/the-diamond-operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [split documentation](https://perldoc.pl/functions/split) explains what happens when each argument is omitted.

> If only PATTERN is given, EXPR defaults to `$_`.

Comment: And the third operand defaults to 0. `split(/,/)` is short for `split(/,/, $_, 0)`.

Comment: @ysth, What I said is correct. `split(/,/)` is short for `split(/,/, $_, 0)`. But yeah, `split(/,/, $_, 0)` and thus `split(/,/)` get optimized to `split(/,/, $_, 5)` when on the RHS of a 4-item assignment. And this is actually documented (because it's an imperfect optimization because it happens even if the assignment is evaluated in scalar context).

Comment: @ikegami you are arguably correct, it defaults to 0 and then the 0 is optimized to 5.  deleting my comment

Answer (score 3):

This code uses a number of shortcuts.  It is equivalent to this:

```
while(defined($_ = readline(ARGV))) {
   chomp($_);
   my($v1, $v2, $v3, $v4) = split(/,/, $_, 5);
```